# Py list is not giving expected result

Tags: python, list

Why is arr[0]  * 7 changing all element of arr to 7 and also  arr[1][0] does not exist but the interpreter is result is 7. I am quite confused rn

```
    arr =[[]]*3
    arr[0].append(7)
    print(arr[0])   #[7]
    print(arr)      #[[7],[7],[7]]
    try:
       print(arr[1][0])  #7
    except IndexError:
       print("0")
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [[]] * 3
```

Creates an array of 3 references to the same list, so `arr[1][0]` is accessing the copy of the first list you initialized.
What you probably want is:

```
arr = [[], [], []]
```

Or the more generic version:

```
arr = [[] for _ in range(N)]
```

That way when you do the appending you obtain the desired result:

```
arr[0].append(7) # [[7], [], []]
```

You can have a more detailed explanation reading my answer on [Populate list of list with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64406155/8873120)

Comment: You're correct, I just want to add that "link-safe" equivalent to `arr = [[]] * N` is `arr = [[] for _ in range(N)]`, there is no need to hardcode list of the list creation

Answer (score 1):

you have a two dimensional array but assign a value to the all references. you will see it if you

```
print(arr)
```

before and after every assignment

Answer (score 1):

Your first line does not actually create a matrix, it creates an array of three elements, where each element refers to the same object: an empty array.
As such, `arr[o].append(7)` is exactly the same thing as `arr[1].append(7)` or `arr[2].append(7)`.

If you want an easy way to visualize all that, try http://pythontutor.com/live.html#mode=edit

To easily create matrixes, use:
`matrix = [[0 for _ in range(y)] for _ in range(x)]`